# heroku push rejected failed to compile ruby app / freetds is missing

Tags: ruby, heroku

I'm new to Heroku and I'm trying to update the stack for an app but my attempts to push keep getting rejected. In each case it's telling me that freetds is missing but I've tried following several responses on other posts as well as docs I've been able to find. freetds is installed via homebrew on my machine. I tried  Following is the output.

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching git://github.com/centresource/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git
remote:        Fetching git://github.com/contextoptional/oauth-ruby.git
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
remote:        Installing rake 10.3.2
remote:        Installing i18n 0.6.11
remote:        Installing json 1.8.1
remote:        Installing minitest 5.4.0
remote:        Installing atomic 1.1.14
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.1.3
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.1
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.1.4
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing actionview 4.1.4
remote:        Installing rack 1.5.2
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.2
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.1.4
remote:        Installing mime-types 1.25.1
remote:        Installing polyglot 0.3.5
remote:        Installing treetop 1.4.15
remote:        Installing mail 2.5.4
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.1.4
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.1.4
remote:        Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.1.4
remote:        Using activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 4.1.0.pre from git://github.com/centresource/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git (at 4.1-stable)
remote:        Installing rails-observers 0.1.2
remote:        Installing activeresource 4.0.0
remote:        Installing bcrypt-ruby 3.1.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.7.1
remote:        Installing execjs 2.0.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.3.0
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing railties 4.1.4
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
remote:        Installing daemons 1.1.9
remote:        Installing multipart-post 1.2.0
remote:        Installing databasedotcom 1.3.2
remote:        Installing orm_adapter 0.4.0
remote:        Installing warden 1.2.3
remote:        Installing devise 3.1.1
remote:        Installing eventmachine 1.0.8
remote:        Installing excon 0.38.0
remote:        Installing hike 1.2.3
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 3.0.4
remote:        Installing kaminari 0.14.1
remote:        Installing mailchimp-api 2.0.5
remote:        Installing mono_logger 1.1.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.10.1
remote:        Using oauth 0.4.7 from git://github.com/contextoptional/oauth-ruby.git (at master)
remote:        Installing pg 0.17.0
remote:        Installing rack-protection 1.5.3
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing sprockets 2.11.0
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 2.1.3
remote:        Installing rails 4.1.4
remote:        Installing redis 3.1.0
remote:        Installing redis-namespace 1.5.0
remote:        Installing sinatra 1.4.5
remote:        Installing vegas 0.1.11
remote:        Installing resque 1.25.2
remote:        Installing xml-simple 1.1.4
remote:        Installing salesforce_bulk 1.0.3
remote:        Installing sass 3.2.19
remote:        Installing sass-rails 4.0.3
remote:        Installing thin 1.6.2
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        /tmp/build_f5103be1ef5608a727364f54cfa6332a/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
remote:        checking for sybfront.h... no
remote:        -----
remote:        freetds is missing.
remote:        -----
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_f5103be1ef5608a727364f54cfa6332a/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
remote:        --enable-lookup
remote:        --disable-lookup
remote:        --with-iconv-dir
remote:        --without-iconv-dir
remote:        --with-iconv-include
remote:        --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
remote:        --with-iconv-lib
remote:        --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/
remote:        --with-freetds-dir
remote:        --without-freetds-dir
remote:        --with-freetds-include
remote:        --without-freetds-include=${freetds-dir}/include
remote:        --with-freetds-lib
remote:        --without-freetds-lib=${freetds-dir}/
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_f5103be1ef5608a727364f54cfa6332a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.6.1 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_f5103be1ef5608a727364f54cfa6332a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.6.1/ext/tiny_tds/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing tiny_tds (0.6.1), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install tiny_tds -v '0.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching git://github.com/centresource/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git
remote:        Fetching git://github.com/contextoptional/oauth-ruby.git
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
remote:        Installing rake 10.3.2
remote:        Installing i18n 0.6.11
remote:        Installing json 1.8.1
remote:        Installing minitest 5.4.0
remote:        Installing atomic 1.1.14
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.1.3
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.1
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.1.4
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing actionview 4.1.4
remote:        Installing rack 1.5.2
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.2
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.1.4
remote:        Installing mime-types 1.25.1
remote:        Installing polyglot 0.3.5
remote:        Installing treetop 1.4.15
remote:        Installing mail 2.5.4
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.1.4
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.1.4
remote:        Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.1.4
remote:        Using activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 4.1.0.pre from git://github.com/centresource/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git (at 4.1-stable)
remote:        Installing rails-observers 0.1.2
remote:        Installing activeresource 4.0.0
remote:        Installing bcrypt-ruby 3.1.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.7.1
remote:        Installing execjs 2.0.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.3.0
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing railties 4.1.4
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
remote:        Installing daemons 1.1.9
remote:        Installing multipart-post 1.2.0
remote:        Installing databasedotcom 1.3.2
remote:        Installing orm_adapter 0.4.0
remote:        Installing warden 1.2.3
remote:        Installing devise 3.1.1
remote:        Installing eventmachine 1.0.8
remote:        Installing excon 0.38.0
remote:        Installing hike 1.2.3
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 3.0.4
remote:        Installing kaminari 0.14.1
remote:        Installing mailchimp-api 2.0.5
remote:        Installing mono_logger 1.1.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.10.1
remote:        Using oauth 0.4.7 from git://github.com/contextoptional/oauth-ruby.git (at master)
remote:        Installing pg 0.17.0
remote:        Installing rack-protection 1.5.3
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing sprockets 2.11.0
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 2.1.3
remote:        Installing rails 4.1.4
remote:        Installing redis 3.1.0
remote:        Installing redis-namespace 1.5.0
remote:        Installing sinatra 1.4.5
remote:        Installing vegas 0.1.11
remote:        Installing resque 1.25.2
remote:        Installing xml-simple 1.1.4
remote:        Installing salesforce_bulk 1.0.3
remote:        Installing sass 3.2.19
remote:        Installing sass-rails 4.0.3
remote:        Installing thin 1.6.2
remote:        
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_f5103be1ef5608a727364f54cfa6332a/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
remote:        checking for sybfront.h... no
remote:        -----
remote:        freetds is missing.
remote:        -----
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_f5103be1ef5608a727364f54cfa6332a/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
remote:        --enable-lookup
remote:        --disable-lookup
remote:        --with-iconv-dir
remote:        --without-iconv-dir
remote:        --with-iconv-include
remote:        --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
remote:        --with-iconv-lib
remote:        --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/
remote:        --with-freetds-dir
remote:        --without-freetds-dir
remote:        --with-freetds-include
remote:        --without-freetds-include=${freetds-dir}/include
remote:        --with-freetds-lib
remote:        --without-freetds-lib=${freetds-dir}/
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_f5103be1ef5608a727364f54cfa6332a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.6.1 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_f5103be1ef5608a727364f54cfa6332a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.6.1/ext/tiny_tds/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing tiny_tds (0.6.1), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install tiny_tds -v '0.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Comment: What are those other posts describing the things you tried?

Comment: I tried `bundle install --binstubs --path=vendor` and adding to the application.rb file `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`.

I read through several posts but most did not seem wholly relevant. But then, like I said, I'm new to this so I might not be doing the best job at hunting down an answer. Is there any other information I should provide?